# .Net Core API : No Routes matched the supplied value

Tags: .net, api, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have been doing this for hours now. What am I doing wrong here?

BaseController Route

```
[Route("api/v{v:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
[Authorize]
public class BaseControllerV2 : ControllerBase
{
}
```

Controller Route

```
public class OrdersController : BaseControllerV2
{

private readonly IOrderService _iOrderService;

public OrdersController(IOrderService iOrderService)
{
    _iOrderService = iOrderService;
}

  

  /// <summary>
    /// Retrieve order details
    /// </summary>
    [HttpGet("{orderNo:int}", Name = nameof(GetOrderByOrderNo))]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Business.Models.V2.Order>> GetOrderByOrderNo([FromRoute]int orderNo, [BindRequired, FromQuery]int agencyNo, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var result = await _iOrderService.GetOrderByOrderNo(orderNo, agencyNo, cancellationToken);

        if (result == null) return NotFound();

        return Ok(result);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Create quote
    /// </summary>
    [HttpPost(Name = nameof(CreateQuote))]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status201Created)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Business.Models.V2.Order>> CreateQuote([FromBody]Business.Models.V2.Order order, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var result = await _iOrderService.CreateQuote(order, cancellationToken);

        return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetOrderByOrderNo), new { orderNo = result.OrderNo, agencyNo = result.AgencyNo, cancellationToken}, result);
    }

}
```

I have tried the solution to other related questions but CreatedAtAction still can't find the endpoint.

Comment: Use Route attribute to define route

Comment: You have defined Route attribute on base controller. Define it on derived controller

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `GetOrderByOrderNo` accepts only 1 parameter `HttpGet("{orderNo:int}"`, but you're trying to pass 3, add other 2 params to HttpGet

Comment: I do have a query parameter setup on the endpoint. public async Task<ActionResult<Business.Models.V2.Order>> GetOrderByOrderNo([FromRoute]int orderNo, [BindRequired, FromQuery]int agencyNo, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing one parameter from controller route - `{v:apiVersion}`, try this:

```cs
    public async Task<ActionResult<Business.Models.V2.Order>> CreateQuote([FromRoute] ApiVersion version, [FromBody]Business.Models.V2.Order order, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var result = await _iOrderService.CreateQuote(order, cancellationToken);

        return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetOrderByOrderNo), new { v = version.ToString(), orderNo = result.OrderNo, agencyNo = result.AgencyNo, cancellationToken}, result);
    }
```

Here you can find example: https://github.com/microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning/blob/master/samples/aspnetcore/BasicSample/Controllers/HelloWorldController.cs